# Stolen phone. Secure and erase

Tags: samsung

So my galaxy S20plus was stolen,  though my Google account,  I did the secure and erase notification.  As only this or the ring option showed.  Anyhow,  now when I check my Google find my device site,  it's still the same,  and shows me that since I lost the phone it wasn't online,  does that mean my data are safe? I'm worried for my bank apps and so.  Does it not being online since then guarantee me that he didn't manage to crack me security code? As I had the pin thing to lock the screen.  Thanks

Comment: You don't need to go online for extracting data from a phone. The better question is how is the phone protected, is a PIN/password/pattern set and how complex is it.

Comment: 4 digit pin might be possible to guess (bruteforcing) but the attacker only has 140 attempts. if your pin is not 1234 no worry your data is secure

Comment: I hope you notified your bank and changed all your passwords